# Combine figures into one new figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image]

I obtained many figures like the figure at the link. In every figure, I have two graphs. I want to take left graphs from every figure and combine them into one new figure. For ex; I have 3 figures.I will obtain one figure that includes only the left graphs from 3 figures. Finally, I will have one figure which have 3 left graphs in it.

Comment: See: [`subplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

Comment: @excaza I have already plotted graphs?  Does subplot make sense?

Comment: You should refine your question.  Do you want a figure window with multiple axes on it, such as subplot would give.  Or do you want a figure window with one axis on it, with that axis having multiple lines on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`copyobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html?refresh=true) to accomplish this. You will want to copy each `axes` object from the old figure to the new figure. Also since legends are separate from the axes, you will need to recreate those as well. The following script should be able to accomplish this. You only need to supply the number of subplots in each original figure (defaults to 2) and an array of figure handles to copy from.

```
figures = [fig1, fig2];    
nSubplots = 2;

% Create all of the new figure that we're going to copy into
for k = 1:nSubplots
    newfig(k) = figure();
end

% For each existing figure, copy all axes
for k = 1:numel(figures)

    % Find the legends
    legends = findall(figures(k), 'tag', 'legend');

    % Sort by x position so we know which goes with which axes
    positions = get(legends, 'Position');
    positions = cat(1, positions{:});
    [~, sortind] = sort(positions(:,1));
    legends = legends(sortind);

    % Now we want to copy each axes in this figure
    for n = 1:nSubplots
        % Retrieve the axes handle
        ax = subplot(1,nSubplots,1, 'Parent', figures(k));

        % Determine the position of the axes in the new figure
        s = subplot(1, numel(figures), k, 'Parent', newfig(n));
        pos = get(s, 'Position');
        delete(s)

        % Copy old axes over to this figure
        newax = copyobj(ax, newfig(n));
        set(newax, 'Position', pos);

        % Copy the legend from the old plot as well
        legend(newax, get(legends(n), 'string'))
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to see 3 graphs seperately. Your code combines in one graph. I want to see 3 graphs seperately in the figure. I have xlabel, ylabel, weight, legends in my graphs. I want to see 3 graphs with xlabel,ylabel, legend.. etc.

Comment: @DenizBaturay See the update at the end

Comment: @Suaver Thank you for answers but I have already plotted the data. You defined left and right and plotted in your code but I already did this and obtained figure. Now, I ask how can I organize these figures?

Comment: @DenizBaturay The reason I plot them in my code is to show a complete working example. Do you have handles to the plot objects that you created? Do you have a script which generates the plots?

Comment: @DenizBaturay Updated with an example that should work if you don't have any plot handles

Comment: @Suaver Thank you very much for your effort but I have figure handles.

Comment: @DenizBaturay Then replace the first line of my last solution with your list of figure handles (as the comment above that line says). The rest will work.

Comment: @Suaver Your code works, but I did not understand the problem. I didn't see the graphs at the end. I have legends and bold writings in the axes. May it be the problem? Could you look if I send three of my graphs?

Comment: @DenizBaturay What commands were used to generate the plots? Uploading them and linking to them wouldn't hurt (the originals)

Comment: @Suaver My code is very long to post here because of writing very simple :(

Comment: @DenizBaturay Why not just create the plots in different figures in the first place? Also, I was talking about uploading images not necessarily the code

Comment: Could I delete images after I upload?

Comment: @DenizBaturay Do you have a script which generates these figures? Why can't we modify that script to put them in the right place rather than trying to move them to a new figure. This is non-trivial with labels, legends, annotations, etc.

Comment: @Suaver As I said code is very long. Actually, I will fix the code later because it will take a lot of time. Because of this I tried this way. Anyway i'm so thankful to you :)

Comment: @DenizBaturay I'm not asking for you to post it. Just look for all calls to `figure` and `plot` and modify them so that you plot to a subplot of the same figures rather than plotting to a new figure every time.

Comment: @DenizBaturay I have updated my response and this should work for axes *and* legends

Comment: Thank you but gives error.                                                                  legends = findall(figures(k), 'tag', 'legend');
Error using findall (line 23)
Invalid handles passed to findall.

Comment: @DenizBaturay Did you set the `figures` variable to be a list of all of your figure handles?

Comment: Yes, Ilisted using this code;                                                               fig_files=dir;
for i=3:length(fig_files)
figure(i-2,1)={fig_files(i, 1).name};
end
for i=1:length(figure)
hFigFile = hgload(figure{i,1} );
figures(i,1)=gcf;
end

Comment: @DenizBaturay Oh wait, these figures are in *.fig files?

Comment: Yes they are fig files

Comment: @DenizBaturay Ok. What is the output of `ishghandle(figures)`

Comment: 36x1 logical. every cell value is 1.

Comment: @DenizBaturay Haha I'm pretty stumped here. Try this `legends = findall(figures(1), 'tag', 'legend');`

Comment: It gives 2x1 double.

Comment: @DenizBaturay Ok that's exactly what I would expect. What is the value of `k` when you get the error you reported above?

Comment: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in Untitledss (line 5)
    newfig(k) = figure();
 I posted my code for list figure handles like above then paste your code and I'm getting error here.

Comment: @DenizBaturay maybe `clear all` before running it?

Comment: I did it. Still the same error. Is my code true for ''figures'' variable?

Comment: @DenizBaturay can you paste your entire code into http://pastebin.com and link to it from here so I can see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: I pasted the code.

Comment: @DenizBaturay Can you copy/paste the link here so I can see it?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DJ0vMcSY

Comment: @DenizBaturay OH! It's because you named a variable `figure` on line 3. Change that variable name because that's the name of the function I use later to create a new figure

Comment: Error using handle.handle/get
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in Untitled2sss (line 36)
        legend(newax, get(legends(n), 'string'))

Comment: @DenizBaturay I just made a small tweak. Can you try that to see if it helps?

Comment: still gives the same error. Error using handle.handle/get
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in Untitledlll (line 35)
        legend(newax, get(legends(n), 'string'))